# how to pass values child page to parent without affecting past information

Tags: asp.net

Using asp.net How to pass values from child page to parent page.without affecting past records

I have one Parent Page.So i have to search some user information based on name,mobile no,city and id.
if any one of basis selected record should pass to the parent page without changes of previous entered details.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is AJAX.

If I understand, you want to update a part of the page (search results) without refreshing the rest of the page (search form)? This is easily achieved with JavaScript (being one possibility, another would be something like [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)).

Here is an introduction to AJAX with ASP.NET MVC: [Walkthrough: Adding ASP.NET AJAX Scripting to an MVC Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381533%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

With that said, you don't especially need ASP.NET MVC to do what you want. You could also use jQuery, or plain old vanilla JavaScript.

If what you are building is a "web application", you may want to take a look at SPA frameworks like AngularJS, DurandalJS, etc.

Comment: Sorry, but the question isn't very clear and therefore my answer may not be what you are looking for.